# Sequelize connection to AWS RDS SQL Express Database in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, sql-server-express

I have an elastic beanstalk website and a separate RDS database (SQL Express). When I ssh into the beanstalk instance, I can connect to the database on the server so the security groups are setup up correctly. However, when I use sequelize in my app, I cannot connect to the database.

I receive the below error in sequelize:

```
[SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to lookup instance on web.cluster-qwertyuiop.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND web.cluster-qwertyuiop.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/var/app/current/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js:145:17) {
  parent: ConnectionError: Failed to lookup instance on web.cluster-qwertyuiop.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND web.cluster-qwertyuiop.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
      at ConnectionError (/var/app/current/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
      at /var/app/current/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1077:60
      at /var/app/current/node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js:116:20
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (/var/app/current/node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js:140:16)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:74:17) {
    code: 'EINSTLOOKUP'
  },
```

This is my connection string:

```
new Sequelize('DATABASE', username, password, {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
        requestTimeout: 300000,
        options: {
            driver: 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
            instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
            trustedConnection: true,
        },
    },
    logging: false,
    port: 1433,
    host: 'web.cluster-qwertyuiop.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    pool: {
        max: 20,
        min: 3,
        idle: 20000,
        evict: 0,
        acquire: 20000,
        handleDisconnects: true,
    },
```

There's very little to find online when trying to connect to MS SQL instances. I've been stuck on this one for a few days now.

Comment: There is a high probability that the issue is in your app code. Since you are unable to establish a connection from your app to the RDS. You might wanna have a look at that.

Comment: @Shweta, No I'm not able to establish a connection from my app to RDS. I'm able to establish a connection on the server to RDS.

Comment: That's what I am saying. There might be an issue in your code. I would suggest testing just the connection part of code separately to confirm this.

Comment: @Shweta the code snippet above is what i use to connect. The error pops up when i run the authenticate() function. any thoughts?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I have no trouble running the code locally connected to my local instance.

Comment: I had to remove "cluster" from the url, facepalm

Comment: Did you not copy the url from the endpoint given on the RDS dashboard?